# Can I define a view in eclipse which shows html files?

Tags: java, html, eclipse, browser, eclipse-plugin

I wonder if there is a way to define a view in eclipse which can render and show html files or with other words a view which works like a browser! I mean  a view  for an eclipse plugin.

For example if I can define a browser based on org.eclipse.swt.browser and associate it to viewcontentprovider?

I don't want to open an html file within eclipse editor. I am writing an eclipse plugin and I want to open some html forms or xforms in a view instead of eclipse internal web browser or an external web browser.

Answer (score 8):

Just rightclick your html file in eclipse and select `Open with -> Web Browser`.

Comment: My quesiton was something else, may be I didn't explain it clearly! I don't want to open an html file in eclipse!

Comment: I am sorry, but I still don't understand what you are trying to do instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Aptana eclipse plugin. It has some WYSIWYG capabilities.

http://www.aptana.com/

Comment: I will check Aptana. Thank you fo your answer.